# Select from 3 tables with one-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question.In my database I have 3 tables:

Articles:

```
id  title  content  date
```

Tags:

```
id  name
```

Tags_in_news:

```
id  news_id  tag_id
```

Where news_id is foreign key for news table and tag_id is foreign key for tag table...How to select the articles and all tags attached to them?
I create a query but it select a news for each tag:

```
SELECT * FROM articles join tags_in_news
ON articles.id = tags_in_news.news_id
join tags on tags.id = tags_in_news.tag_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: where is article table? is that news table you are referring?

Comment: It's getting more confusing; not less :-(

Comment: can you describe the sample out put how it should look like ?

Comment: Do you use oracle or mysql?

Comment: Now if I have an article and 4 tags attached to them I get: title article-first tag,title article-second tag,title article-last tag...

Comment: mysql.....................

Comment: and what do you want to get instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is pretty close, and since you are doing joining it will list all the matching rows and you will get multiple rows for article per tag.
In mysql there is a function called `group_concat()` which you can use along with `group by` so that all the tags associated with an article is concat by a comma and then display it for each article.

```
select
a.title,
a.content,
a.date,
group_concat(t.name) as name
from tags_in_news tin
inner join article a on a.id = tin.news_id
inner join tags t on t.id = tin.tag_id
group by a.id
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a48d4/2)**

Comment: The query select only one tag for article

Comment: No it should not return one tag per articel, check the demo in my update

Answer (score 2):

Try GROUP BY article and grouping tags as comma separated value

something like this:

```
SELECT 
date, a.title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name) as tags_attached
FROM articles a 
JOIN tags_in_news tin ON a.id = tin.news_id
JOIN tags t ON t.id = tin.tag_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Avisheks if the article have many tags with this select it show only one

Comment: @user3611170,If an article have multiple tags but with the same name it will show you all the tags having distinct names. If you want them all remove the DISTINCT from GROUP_CONCAT